# Dependency Injection of same service but different options

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a transient service called *MyService* which implements *IMyService*, with injected *IConfiguration* like:

```cs
public interface IMyService
{
}

public class MyService
{
  private readonly string _value;
  public MyService(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
     // in some cases i want SomeConfig1:Key1 and in some other SomeConfig2:Key2
     _value = configuration.GetValue<string>("SomeConfig1:Key1");
  }
}
```

also there is a configuration in **appsettings.json** like:

```json
"SomeConfig1": { "Key1":"Value1" },
"SomeConfig2": { "Key2":"Value2"}
```

I want to use same service but with different configuration values based on context in which service is used. The way, I think this should be done is using dependency injection, but I am not able to find the solution for that, only thing I find out is the way to resolve different services that are implements the same interface using Service Resolver, but in my case I want to use same (one and only) service but with different values from configuration.

Comment: Don't do this. Subclass a base implementation and have each subclass take a different configuration option and implement a different interface.

Comment: How do you define when you want Key1 and when Key2?

Comment: Maybe you can change and implement the implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72749971/13092211) according to your scenario.