# Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext' For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, minimal-apis

I'm trying to to create a minimal API. unable to resolve the below error.
"Unable to create an Object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time. due to this reason not able to do Migration.

**Program.cs**

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

var sqlconnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDbConnection");
sqlconnectionBuilder.UserID = builder.Configuration["UserId"];
sqlconnectionBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["Password"];
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(sqlconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommandRepo, CommandRepo>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommandRepo,CommandRepo>();
```

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
    
}
public DbSet<Command> commands => Set<Command>();
}
```

**project.csproj**

```
   <PackageReference 

Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.6">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />  
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to manipulate the connection string, you can use DbContextFactory.

Create custom factory;

```
public class AppDbContextScopedFactory : IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext> _dbContextFactory;

    public AppDbContextScopedFactory(IDbContextFactory<AppDbContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();

        context.Database.SetConnectionString("yourconnectionstring");

        //Also you can set public dbcontext properties. Properties will be reseted each dbcontext creation.

        return context;
    }
}
```

Register the `AppDbContextScopedFactory` to service collection with implementation.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>((provider, options) =>
   {
       options.UseSqlServer("initialconnectionstring");
   });

   services.AddScoped<AppDbContextScopedFactory>();
   services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AppDbContextScopedFactory>().CreateDbContext());
}
```

I didn't test without initial connection string, maybe it will works without it.

Comment: Actually the goal is not to manipulate the connection string trying to set the userid and password in dotnet-secrets. let me try this approach

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code samples provided by you and after few changes and an addition in the connection string it worked for me. Just do the following:

```
    var sqlconnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString = 
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDbConnection");
    sqlconnectionBuilder.UserID = builder.Configuration["UserId"];
    sqlconnectionBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["Password"];
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => 
    opt.UseSqlServer(sqlconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString));
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommandRepo, CommandRepo>();
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

Copy the code mentioned above and paste it above var app = Builder.Build() because services are registered before this method as WebApplicationBuilder.Build() has to build the services.

Then just add

```
    TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

for avoiding below mentioned error

> The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

if you have not added this in connection string.

your code will work then.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified my mistake. before builder.Build was instantiated before var sql code block. I  have moved the below code to after the sql block it works fine.

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

**After**

```
var sqlconnectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString = 
 builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDbConnection");
 sqlconnectionBuilder.UserID = builder.Configuration["UserId"];
 sqlconnectionBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["Password"];
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => 
 opt.UseSqlServer(sqlconnectionBuilder.ConnectionString));
 builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommandRepo, CommandRepo>();
 builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

 var app = builder.Build();
```